# Is my method a good one for evaluating $\displaystyle\int_0^1(x+2i\sqrt{x\tan(x)})(x-2i\sqrt{x\tan(x)})\cos(x)-2\cos(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

So I have a younger friend of mine (who I've mentioned before) who loves math, especially when it comes to integrals, and will sometimes give me (somewhat) abominations of integrals which I'm usually able to evaluate. Last night, this friend of mine gave me this integral to evaluate:

$$\int_0^1(x+2i\sqrt{x\tan(x)})(x-2i\sqrt{x\tan(x)})\cos(x)-2\cos(x)dx$$

which I felt that maybe I might be able to do. Here is my attempt at doing so:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1(x+2i\sqrt{x\tan(x)})(x-2i\sqrt{x\tan(x)})\cos(x)-2\cos(x)dx \\
&= \int_0^1(x^2+2ix\sqrt{x\tan(x)}-2ix\sqrt{x\tan(x)}+4x\tan(x))\cos(x)-2\cos(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^1(x^2+4x\tan(x))\cos(x)-2\cos(x)dx \\
&= \int_0^1x^2\cos(x)+4x\sin(x)-2\cos(x)dx \\
&= \int_0^1x^2\cos(x)dx+2x\sin(x)+2x\sin(x)-2\cos(x)dx \\
&= \int_0^1\dfrac d{dx}\left(x^2\cos(x)+2x\sin(x)\right)dx \\
&= \left[x^2\cos(x)+2x\sin(x)\right]_0^1\\
&=\cos(1)+2\sin(1)
\end{align*}$$

---

### My question

---

Did I evaluate the definite integral that my friend gave me correctly, or what would I do to evaluate it?

Comment: I didn't finish reading your attempt, but to make your work look nicer, you can use the "begin/end align" environment so that each equal sign is aligned vertically instead horizontally. When the equal signs are aligned horizontally, it's a little hassle to drag the mouse cursor left and right on the scroll bar.

Comment: @Accelerator wait what scroll bar? I don't see any.

Comment: Oh, I'm using Chrome on my Galaxy phone. My screen doesn't show the scroll bar on your math unless I purposely swipe left and right.

Comment: @Accelerator Ah okay, sorry about the confusion. I'm currently using a Chromebook right now so that's why the scroll bar doesn't show for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the difference of squares formula to go from the first to the third step in one stride. Also, the way you wrote the integrand as a derivative is incorrect. Try differentiating to check. To get the indefinite integral, all you need to do is integrate by parts - integrating the trig function and differentiating the polynomial coefficient. So, $\int x^2\cos xdx=(x^2-2)\sin x+2x\cos x$ and $\int x\sin xdx=\sin x-x\cos x$. So, the answer is actually $-\sin(1)+2\cos(1)+4\sin(1)-4\cos(1)-2\sin(1)=\sin(1)-2\cos(1)$

Comment: Ah yes, I should probably practice my derivatives then haha.

Comment: @CrSb0001 You got the gist of the problem, it is just that you made a simple mistake while integrating. Also, your friend is "under" simplifying the problem when it is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_0^1\left(x^2 \cos x+4 x \sin x-2 \cos x\right) d x \\
= & \int_0^1\left(x^2-2\right) d(\sin x)+4 \int_0^1 x \sin x d x \\
= & {\left[\left(x^2-2\right) \sin x\right]_0^1-2 \int_0^1 x \sin x+4 \int_0^1 x \sin x d x } \\
= & -\sin 1-2 \int_0^1 x d (\cos x) \\
= & -\sin 1-2 [x\cos x]_0^1+2 \int_0^1 \cos x d x \\
= & \sin 1-2 \cos 1 
\end{aligned}
$$